# How to deal with the columns with the same prefix name in batches in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame named 'test' like below,

```
Day                     Rain      SWC_11    SWC_12    SWC_13    SWC_21   SWC_22   
01/01/2019  00:00:00     0.0        51        60        63       60        64 
02/01/2019  00:00:00     0.2        51.5      60.3      63.4     60.8      64.4
03/01/2019  00:00:00     0.0        51.3      60.3      63.3     60.6      64.1 
04/01/2019  00:00:00     0.4        53        62        64       62        65   
05/01/2019  00:00:00     1.0        55        64        66       64        67
```

I want to use a loop function to find the jumps of the SWC data after the rain events, which kind of like find the non-zero Rain data first, then use the next SWC data point to minus the current SWC data point. Now, the problem is I have many 'SWC' columns with the same prefix 'SWC', how to run all of them with a easy loop function maybe.

The expected data frame should be like below,

```
Day                     Rain   SWC_11_jump   SWC_12_jump    SWC_13_jump    SWC_21_jump   SWC_22_jump  
01/01/2019  00:00:00     0.0       0            0             0                 0            0
02/01/2019  00:00:00     0.2      0.5           0.3           0.4               0.8          0.4
03/01/2019  00:00:00     0.0       0            0             0                 0            0
04/01/2019  00:00:00     0.4      1.7           1.7           0.7               1.4          0.9
05/01/2019  00:00:00     1.0       2            2             2                 2            2
```

I am not at loop function, hope someone could help out. Thanks.

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: @akrun I have re-edited the question.

Comment: Use gather() from dplyr/tidyverse to convert your SWC columns to a factor in a single column

Comment: you can use `paste0("SWC_", x)` to iterate over the SWC columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't iterate

The power of R is in working on multiple things at the same time. Yes, underwater thigns are done sequentially, but every step in R that is done sequentially involves a lot of memory access, and movement of data. Now for this example it doesn't matter that much (assuming you don't really care whether it takes 1 ms or 10 ms), but in general you'll want to use the parallel functions of R as much as you can.

What is done when you run your code here, is that at every iteration the whole data.frame is rewritten. Meaning it is read, one data point is changed, and it is written back to memory. And then we get the next iteration. But we don't need the entire data frame for every calculation, all operations on one column can be done independently from the others.

That means we can use the `apply`-function. As a beginner, it may seem intimidating, but once you're used to it you'll find it (and its cousins) are very powerful, and it makes your code more robust. And it also means you don't have to initialize anything to `NA`, you can just write the answers.

We'll write `difference_function` later, but getting it to the output looks like this:

```
output <- apply(test[,grepl("SWC_", colnames(test))], 2, difference_function)
```

This will take a subset with only the columns starting with SWC, and apply the same function over each column (The `2` indicates we want to apply the function over the columns, a 1 would go by row).

Within `difference_function`, we can do something similar. We don't want to subtract 2 numbers for 5 times, we want to subtract *5 pairs of numbers*. So we can subtract col from col, offset by one from each other. We only have to think a bit about the borders. For the first subtraction, it seems you always want 0 as an answer, so we can subtract `Inf` from the first value. And we never want to subtract the last value from something, so we can drop that.

And one more provision: we never want the difference to be negative. We can accomplish that by taking the maximum of `0` and the calculated difference, for each element. This will give us:

```
difference_function <- function(col) {
  pmax(0, col - c(Inf, col[-length(col)]))
}
```

The name `pmax` stands for "parallel maximum", so for each element it will take the maximum of (0, element). And it will do so in one go.

Finally:

You don't have to specify the function seperately. If you're just going to use it once, you can just give it directly to apply.

And if you know how many columns in total you have, you can assign to `test` directly, you'll just have to set columnnames afterwards.

```
test[,8:12] <- apply(test[3:7], 2, function(col) {
  pmax(0, col - c(Inf, col[-length(col)]))
})
colnames(test)[8:12] <- paste0(colnames(test)[grep('SWC', colnames(test))], '_jump')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explicit explanation. I also found the problem of loop function when I try to cope with my large data frame lately. it's quite time-consuming and proceed too slowly. Although I haven't used the apply function until now, I would like to give a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution with my friends' help.

```
# find target columns
target_colnames <- colnames(test)[which(grepl("SWC_", colnames(test)) == TRUE)]
output_colnames <- paste(target_colnames,"_jump",sep="")
test[output_colnames] <- NA

## if rain≠0, then use the next SWC data point subtract the current data point.
for (i in 1:(nrow(test)-1)){
for (j in 1:length(target_colnames)){
if (test$Rain[[i]] != 0){
test[output_colnames[j]][i,]  <- test[target_colnames[j]][i+1,] - 
test[target_colnames[j]][i,]
}
}
}
```